# Can I use viewDidLoad method in UITableviewCell?

Tags: iphone, ios

Can I use `viewDidLoad` method in `UITableviewCell`?

Comment: are you interested in customized table view cell?

Comment: what to do ,first tell by ViewDidLoad?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

No you don't write viewDidLoad in Custom cell class subclassing UITableViewCell(It;s part of UIViewController) .you have a method called

```
-(void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
}
```

where in you can define frames and all for custom cell's controls.Refer [Apple's UITableviewCell reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

**Note however** that 'viewDidLoad' is called ***only once*** in the lifetime of the object; it is rather like an initializer in general OO programming. However, 'layoutSubviews' ***will be called many times*** on each cell (depending on issues like scrolling and so on).  It's important to realize that for this reson many of the things you "usually do" in viewDidLoad, you ***can not do*** in layoutSubviews.

## Note that viewDidLoad is called *once* only: layoutSubviews is called *often*.

It will just be a simple function if you write it.

[Tutorial for custom cell](http://jainmarket.blogspot.in/2009/05/creating-custom-table-view-cell.html)

Comment: Can you please tell me that what is the first method which is called automatically in uiTableViewCell?

Comment: – initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier: is called first.Ihave given a tutorial above you can see.

Answer (score 18):

If you're trying to initialise some IBOutlets of your UITableViewCell, you may want to go for the awakeFromNib() call:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Do your stuff
    // myIBOutlet.text = "Hello" 
}
```

Comment: `awakeFromNib` seems like the closest thing to `viewDidLoad` indeed.

Answer (score 14):

Better to call `super.layoutSubviews()` as well. Swift syntax:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
}
```

Answer (score 13):

An `awakeFromNib()` is similar to a `viewDidLoad()`, thus it will run less often and must be called for initialization commands.

A `layoutSubviews()` is similar to a `viewWillAppear()`, so it should be called when you want to change something in the view presentation. For instance, when a user changes the phone orientation and the app needs to update some of the view's specific configuration, like size, colour and position.

Apple's documentation on the `awakeFromNib()` method:

> **Summary**
>
> Prepares the receiver for service after it has been loaded from an
>   Interface Builder archive, or nib file.
>
> Declaration
>
> `func awakeFromNib()`
>
> **Discussion**
>   The nib-loading infrastructure sends an awakeFromNib message to each
>   object recreated from a nib archive, but only after all the objects in
>   the archive have been loaded and initialized. When an object receives
>   an awakeFromNib message, **it is guaranteed to have all its outlet and**
>   **action connections already established.**
>
> You must call the super implementation of awakeFromNib to give parent
>   classes the opportunity to perform any additional initialization they
>   require. Although the default implementation of this method does
>   nothing, many UIKit classes provide non-empty implementations. You may
>   call the super implementation at any point during your own
>   awakeFromNib method.

Answer (score 2):

The UIKit function `viewDidLoad` is a member of UIViewController, and UITableViewCell does not inherit from it.  You can write a method **named** `viewDidLoad` if you desire, but it will not be called like it is in a UIViewController subclass.

Comment: Can you please tell me that what is the first method which is called automatically in uiTableViewCell?

Comment: It is not as simple as that.  It depends on what kind of UITableView you are using.  Traditionally, a UITableView would ask for a custom cell via the `cellForRowAtIndex` delegate method.  It would help a lot to know more about what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is an old thread, but a pattern I sometimes use (especially if I have a base class for my custom cells):

1. Add a BOOL property, call it something like "cellAlreadyDidLoad".  I named it that way because BOOL will default to NO, so I don't have to worry about setting it in an init method.
2. Create a cellDidLoad method, named so with the intent that it's kind of like the viewDidLoad that we all know and love.
3. Override the layoutSubviews method and add:

   ```
   if (!self.cellAlreadyDidLoad)
   {
       [self cellDidLoad];
       self.cellAlreadyDidLoad = YES;
   }
   ```

Now you have a method, cellDidLoad, that will only be called once, knowing that the UI elements (including your IBOutlets) will be present.  Very much like viewDidLoad on a view controller.

Answer (score 1):

If your UITableViewCell has a variable then you can use didSet like so

```
var stickers:[Sticker]? {
    didSet {
        if let stickers = stickers {
            //do some initialisation 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If You are loading your UITableViewCell from XIB or Storyboard then `initWithCoder()` and `awakeFromNib()` methods are called(in the same order).

If you initialise your UITableViewCell programmatically then they won't be called.

Finally, `prepareForReuse()` will be called on a table view cell when it is being added to the pool of cells. In this method, you should reset the table view cell as if it were new (e.g. clean up text fields, labels, ...).

So I would suggest you to use `awakeFromNib()` method to setup your UITableViewCell.

For eg:-

```
class YourTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

       //do some work here that needs to happen only once, you don’t wanna change them later.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

YES you can write `viewDidLoad` in `UITableViewCell` but `viewDidLoad` is not delegate method of `UITableViewCell` so it will not called automatically so you have to call it manually by  `[self viewDidLoad]` to execute your code.

Comment: Can you please tell me that what is the first method which is called automatically in uiTableViewCell?

Answer (score 0):

you can use initWithFrame for UITableViewCell or UICollectionViewCell or to any Subclass of UIView.

```
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
       // Initialisation code here
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: This isn't called for me.

Comment: it will call only if cell is created the dynamically otherwise you can use `-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder` or `- (void)awakeFromNib` for Initialization

Comment: Dynamically means what exactly?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this works fine:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    //your code here
}
```