# UITapGestureRecognizer on custom table view cell doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to add a gesture recognizer for an image in a custom table view cell. For some reason I can't seem to make it work though. Here's my code

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    heartImage.userInteractionEnabled = true
    let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:Selector("onHeartTap"))
    gesture.delegate = self
    heartImage.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
}

func onHeartTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) 
    print("TAPPED")
}
```

The function awakeFromNib() gets called correctly, but onHeartTap() never gets called when tapping the image. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try to specify the number of taps
        `gesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1`
        `gesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1`

Comment: I think you need to include a ':' on the end of the method signature `Selector("onHeartTap:")` (NB: 100% untested thinking)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

User interaction was enabled for the image but not for the cell.

Enabled it for the cell from the storyboard and everything works. Thanks for the help everybody!

Comment: You will need to add a colon to the selector name: `Selector("onHeartTap")` as mentioned by @user3351949 though.

Answer (score 1):

In your selector name 'onHeartTap' ":" is missing

just replace

```
let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:Selector("onHeartTap"))
```

with

```
let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:Selector("onHeartTap:"))
```

And also any specific reason you are doing this in awakeFromNib?? You can do this on viewWillAppear also.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, that a UIImageView in a UITableViewCell subclass would not trigger the gesture recognizer that I set up.

```
func viewDidLoad() {
    imageView.addGestureRecognizer(UIGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageViewTapped(sender:))))
    imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
}
```

the problem was the `viewDidLoad()` is not called for UITableViewCell:
[Can I use viewDidLoad method in UITableviewCell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10578246/can-i-use-viewdidload-method-in-uitableviewcell/45547195)

set the gesture recognizer in `awakeFromNib()` instead:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    imageView.addGestureRecognizer(UIGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageViewTapped(sender:))))
    imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
}
```